# Delete files older than 7 days in folder and its subfolder

Tags: batch

I need to have a windows batch file which deletes all files which are older than 7 days in a folder and its sub folders without deleting any folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) for usage.